# Hmac with SHa256 Or SHa256 with key appended in the input string? Which is more secure?

Tags: hash, sha256, hmac

Which is a more secure way, Hashing using `SHa256` and appending key in the input string, Or use that key and compute Hmac with SHA256? Or any other other hashing technique which uses a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmac is more secure.

What you are proposing is called "Suffix-MAC" in [Crypto101](https://github.com/crypto101/crypto101.github.io/raw/master/Crypto101.pdf) page 135.  The problem with Suffix-MAC is a collision in the hash function can be used to create existential forgeries.  That is, if h(m1) = h(m2), and if I know suffix-mac(m1), then I also know suffix-mac(m2).

Bellare proved that [HMAC is more robust](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf) because you don't need collision resistance of the hash function for it to be secure.  This is why HMAC-SHA1 is still considered okay even though SHA1 is not considered okay.